# Microsoft Add-in Manifest file option for GetStarted element for Outlook Add-in

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Can I use getstarted element in manifest file for Outlook Add-in? I am developing Outlook Add-in and wanted to use the callout or getstarted element that shows during Add-in Deployment under "Get Add-ins" option.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the feature of adding getStarted element in manifest is not there. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.